# floWeaver does not draw basic diagrams from quick tutorial and does not show error message

Tags: sankey-diagram, extract-error-message

Following the floWeaver tutorial and beginning with the Quickstart where flows are defined, the second step of plotting the flows does not work. The problem is that I do not get any error message.

The code consists of two blocks, with the second block not working..

```
import pandas as pd
flows = pd.read_csv('simple_fruit_sales.csv')

from ipysankeywidget import SankeyWidget
SankeyWidget(links=flows.to_dict('records'))
```

https://sankeyview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html

Python version installed: 3.6.10

floWeaver version: 2.0.0

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue.  The cells execute, but no image is rendered.  I followed the tutorial.  The nbextensions are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have the following installation, other than the package itself.

```
pip install ipysankeywidget

jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipysankeywidget

jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

Comment: I have the same issue. The cells execute, but no image is rendered. I followed the tutorial. The nbextensions are enabled.